# DateTime when saving pandas dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

**Background:** Apparently Google doesn't have a straight answer to a very basic question, so here goes...

I have a pandas `df` with a `Open Date` column [Dtype = object] which (when previewing `df`) is formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`, which is the format I want, great! Not so great however, when I write `df` to a `.csv` which then defaults the formatting to `m/dd/yyyy`.

**Issue:** I have tried just about everything for the `.csv` to output `yyyy-dd-mm` to no avail.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried specifying a date format when writing the `.csv`

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format="%Y%d%d")
```

I have tried changing the format of the column in question, prior to writing to a `.csv`

```
df['Open Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Date'])
```

I have also tried converting the column to a string, to try and force the correct output

```
df['Open Date'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda v: str(v))
```

Despite these attempts, I still get a `m/dd/yyyy` output.

**Help:** where am I embarrasingly going wrong here?

Comment: First, how did you check this?  Did you look at the file in a text editor, or (as I suspect) did you just open it in Excel?  Remember that, when Excel finds a date, it does its OWN formatting.  You have to set the formatting you want Excel to use.

Comment: Most the time I've been opening the file in Excel and in Notepad++. Per the first attempt, I tried forcing an Excel format through `df.to_csv(filename, date_format="%Y-%m-%d")` but no luck. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: You say "when previewing" - previewing how exactly? If the datatype of the column is 'object', it seems likely it's actually a string, so perhaps your method previewing it parses the string that's in the format you don't like. At any rate, `"%Y%d%d"` would never produce `"%Y-%m-%d"` output of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question contained various breaking typos which seems to suggest what may be causing the problem in general.

There's a few issues with what you are saying. Consider:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime

# just some example data, including some datetime and string data
data = [
    {'Open date': datetime(2022, 3, 22, 0, 0), 'value': '1'},
    {'Open date': datetime(2022, 3, 22, 0, 1), 'value': '2'},
    {'Open date': datetime(2022, 3, 22, 0, 2), 'value': '3'}
]
df = DataFrame(data)

# note how the 'Open date' columns is actually a `datetime64[ns]`
# the 'value' string however is what you're saying you're getting, `object`
print(df['Open date'].dtype, df['value'].dtype)

# saving with a silly format, to show it works:
df.to_csv('test.csv', date_format='%Y.%m.%d')
```

The resulting file:

```
,Open date,value
0,2022.03.22,1
1,2022.03.22,2
2,2022.03.22,3
```

I picked a silly format because the default format for me is actually `%Y-%m-%d` .

The most likely issue is that your 'date' column is actually a string column, but the tools you are using to 'preview' your data are interpreting these strings as dates and actually showing them in some other format.

However, with the limited information you provided, it's guesswork. If you provide some example data that demonstrates the issue, it would be easier to say for sure.

Comment: Your answer gets the tick, because it got me thinking - I ran `intl.cpl` from `Windows Search box` and realized that firstly my Regional Settings were defaulting all `short date` values to a format other than what I want. Secondly, I took another look in Notepad++ and noticed the format perfectly align with my `df`.